Wix Toolkit Bootstrapper does not respect custom bitmap
I am using Wix 5.01 in Visual Studio 2022 with two projects: one for the MSI and one for the bootstrapper.  I set custom bitmap images in the MSI project as indicated below.
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="..\assets\dlgbmp_2.png" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="..\assets\dlgbmp_2.png" />
        <UI>
            <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

If I run the MSI through msiexec, I get the custom bitmap images.  If I run the bootstrapper EXE, I get the standard red bitmap images.
I think I have followed the documentation on the Wix Toolkit site.  I included bal:DisplayInternalUICondition in the Bunde.wxs file with values set to "yes" and "no" with no effect.
